# Why do Phonegap need Cross- domain/Cross origin?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a Phonegap mobile app for Android, IOS and Blackberry 10.
I am ready with UI side. My app need to communicate with server.
I am using JQuery Ajax to call Rest API.
***I am having Basic Authorization on server side (IIS Asp.net)***
I am not getting few thing about phonegap

1. **Can't I send simple POST API call without Cross-domain and same for cross origin?**
2. **Why does phonegap/cordova need cross domain, cross origin?**

Comment: with phonegap you can configure "access origin" in config.xml to allow communication with your server and then don't need to bother with cross origin problems.

Comment: yes you are correct i have tested it on android, can you tell how to use Basic Authorization in phonegap? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting Wikipedia:

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows JavaScript on a web page to make XMLHttpRequests to another domain, not the domain the JavaScript originated from.[1] Such "cross-domain" requests would otherwise be forbidden by web browsers, per the same origin security policy.

With Phonegap, the 'domain the JavaScript originated from' would be something like `localhost`, so you need to set up CORS for the remote call to be allowed